# Function Return value at the Beginning

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, swift3

When i call this function , function returns value and then doing all other things. How can i make function to return value end of other things.

```
    func register(parameters : [String : String]) -> Int {

    let headers = [
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "cache-control": "no-cache",
    ]
    var statuscode = 0
    var postD = NSData();
    do {
        let postData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
        postD = postData;
    }catch let error as NSError{
        print(error.description)
    }
    var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(hostUrl)/users")!,
                                      cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                      timeoutInterval: 10.0)

    request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
    request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
    request.HTTPBody = postD

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
    let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
        if (error != nil) {
            print(error)
        } else {
            let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
            statuscode = httpResponse!.statusCode
            print("AFTER HTTP RESPONSE STATUSCODE = \(statuscode)")

        }
    })

    dataTask.resume()
    return statuscode
}
```

Im calling this function like this :

```
let statuscode = client.register(parameters)
        print("denemeeeeeeeeeeeeee\(statuscode)")
```

And this is my output

```
denemeeeeeeeeeeeeee0
AFTER HTTP RESPONSE STATUSCODE = 400
```

Answer (score 1):

`NSURLSession` is an asynchronous API, so I'm afraid your function will always return before the data request completes. You'll have to consider alternative approaches. For example your `register` method could receive a completion closure that you call when your data task is complete.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement a `callback` function to handle this kind of stuff:

```
func register(parameters : [String : String], callback: ((success: Bool, response: NSHTTPURLResponse)->Void){

let headers = [
    "content-type": "application/json",
    "cache-control": "no-cache",
]
var postD = NSData();
do {
    let postData = try NSJSONSerialization.dataWithJSONObject(parameters, options: NSJSONWritingOptions.PrettyPrinted)
    postD = postData;
}catch let error as NSError{
    print(error.description)
}
var request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "\(hostUrl)/users")!,
                                  cachePolicy: .UseProtocolCachePolicy,
                                  timeoutInterval: 10.0)

request.HTTPMethod = "POST"
request.allHTTPHeaderFields = headers
request.HTTPBody = postD

let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()
let dataTask = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { (data, response, error) -> Void in
    if (error != nil) {
        print(error)
    } else {

        let httpResponse = response as? NSHTTPURLResponse
        callback?(success: true, response: httpResponse)


    }
})

dataTask.resume()
}
```

and in your function call:

```
client.register(parameters, callback: { (success, response) in
     var statuscode = 0
     statuscode = response!.statusCode
     print("AFTER HTTP RESPONSE STATUSCODE = \(statuscode)")
})
```

If this is not enough to achieve what you want to do, you could also look into [dispatch groups](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36168541/swift-code-being-executed-asynchronously-even-while-in-completion-handler).

Best of luck.

Comment: this is the simpler solution, you can remove the return as it will not be needed and will be always incorrect

Comment: Correct, I have removed the unused return in my answer.