# Updating MapView based on Geocoded addresses, only one pin of many locations showing

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mapkit, mapkitannotation

I'm having trouble waiting for an asynchronous call and then populating the resulting addresses into placemarks for an `MKMapView`.

The issue is that only one placemark ends up showing on the map's view. I know the others exist because I've debugged it and seen such in the array. It's just not populating the map view fully/refreshing the `MKAnnotation`'s assigned to it.

```
    // Load user sales
    myFirebaseController.loadSales(){(result: [SaleModel]) in
        // Assign result
        self.salesList = result

        let geocoder = CLGeocoder()

        let myGroup = DispatchGroup()

        // For each sale loaded in
        for sale in self.salesList{
            myGroup.enter()

            // Decode the address into coordinates
            geocoder.geocodeAddressString(sale.saleAddress!, completionHandler: {(placemarks, error) -> Void in
                if((error) != nil){
                    print("Error", error!)
                }

                if let placemark = placemarks?.first {
                    // Set the coordinate
                    let coordinates:CLLocationCoordinate2D = placemark.location!.coordinate

                    // Add the annotation
                    self.createMapAnnotation(coordinate: coordinates, title: sale.saleTitle!, address: sale.saleAddress!)
                }

                myGroup.leave()
            })
        }

        myGroup.notify(queue: .main){
            for annotation in self.mapView.annotations {
                self.mapView.removeAnnotation(annotation)

                self.mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
            }
        }
    }
```

As you can see once the dispatch group is left, I try to remove all annotations and re-add them, as a means to refresh it, though I think this is a poor attempt and obviously it doesn't change the map view (which only records the first `sale` annotation of the `self.salesList`)

What am I doing wrong here?

Note:`self.createMapAnnotation()` adds an annotation to the map view.

EDIT: I tried following this - [Wait until swift for loop with asynchronous network requests finishes executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906568/wait-until-swift-for-loop-with-asynchronous-network-requests-finishes-executing) but it doesn't seem to help my situation

Answer (score 0):

Try writing below code after completion of the loop in  myGroup.notify(queue: .main) method.

```
self.mapView?.showAnnotations((self.mapView?.annotations)!, animated: true)
```

Comment: Hmm, doesn't seem to work. I think the issue is that `myGroup.notify(queue: .main)` is only called once and not for each geocode thread