# Swift 4 async call with for loop execute in order using DispatchGroup, DispatchQueue and DispatchSemaphore

Tags: ios, swift

I want to run a for loop in swift in **order**, DispatchGroup will fire them together, so I want to use DispatchQueue and DispatchSemaphore to achieve my goal. I failed to make my program work, how can I force them to wait and run one by one?

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 1)

for c in self.categories {

    dispatchSemaphore.wait()

    dispatchQueue.async(group: dispatchGroup) {

        if let id = c.categoryId {

            dispatchGroup.enter()

            self.downloadProductsByCategory(categoryId: id) { success, data in

                if success, let products = data {

                    self.products.append(products)
                }

                dispatchSemaphore.signal()
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }
        }
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: dispatchQueue) {

    self.refreshOrderTable { _ in

        self.productCollectionView.reloadData()

        NVActivityIndicatorPresenter.sharedInstance.stopAnimating()
    }
}
```

---

Thanks to **Palle**, here is my final code:

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
let dispatchQueue = DispatchQueue(label: "taskQueue")
let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)

dispatchQueue.async {

    for c in self.categories {

        if let id = c.categoryId {

            dispatchGroup.enter()

            self.downloadProductsByCategory(categoryId: id) { success, data in

                if success, let products = data {

                    self.products.append(products)
                }

                dispatchSemaphore.signal()
                dispatchGroup.leave()
            }

            dispatchSemaphore.wait()
        }
    }
}

dispatchGroup.notify(queue: dispatchQueue) {

    DispatchQueue.main.async {

        self.refreshOrderTable { _ in

            self.productCollectionView.reloadData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Unrelated but don't make the `weak self` - `strong self` dance. It's nonsensical because GCD does **not** cause retain cycles.

Comment: If you want to execute in order, why use concurrency anyway? Just create a loop in a background queue and execute your `downloadProductsByCategory` function directly in the loop.

Comment: @Palle `downloadProductsByCategory` itself is async method using alamofire

Comment: Then just put `dispatchSemaphore.wait()` after the call to `downloadProductsByCategory` and `dispatchSemaphore.signal()` in the completion handler.

Comment: @Palle for some reason, when `dispatchSemaphore.wait()` called for the *second* time, the whole program will be blocked there forever. and `downloadProductsByCategory` never receive a callback

Comment: You have to create your semaphore with an initial value of 0, otherwise there will always be two concurrent download tasks. Is your code the same as in my answer?

Comment: Why is there a `semaphore.wait()` call in the first line of the for loop? It should not be there. If `categoryId` is nil, this will cause more `wait` calls than `signal` calls and you will get a deadlock. The `wait` call has to be **after** the call to `downloadProductsByCategory`.

Comment: There is no need for `DispatchGroup` when executing tasks synchronously.. https://pastebin.com/6MgAaJSq

Comment: @Brandon could you please answer the question and provide your solution? Thanks.

Comment: @Timeless https://pastebin.com/4Tt90NJx

Comment: If you want asynchronous but still ordered then: https://pastebin.com/rqrA5Fxm

Comment: Why are you using a dispatch group and a semaphore at the same time? It makes absolutely no sense.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can put the whole loop in a block instead of putting just the download function in a block:

```
dispatchQueue.async {
    for c in self.categories {
        if let id = c.categoryId {
            self.downloadProductsByCategory(categoryId: id) { success, data in
                if success, let products = data {
                    self.products.append(products)
                }

                dispatchSemaphore.signal()
            }
            dispatchSemaphore.wait()
        }
    }
}
```

---

You can simplify your code by using compactMap to unwrap your product ids:

```
for id in self.categories.compactMap({$0.categoryId}) { ... }
```

Comment: thanks, it works. but one more thing, how can I get notified when I get all data? can I use `DispatchGroup` with the current code?

Comment: Just put a `DispatchQueue.main.async { ... }` in the block when you're done with the loop. A dispatch group with a single `enter` and `leave` will of course also work.

Comment: There really is NO need for a dispatch group when the code itself is synchronous. It doesn't make sense. Just call your completion block right after your for-loop.

Comment: THe `dispatchSemaphore` in this answer is not created anywhere.

Comment: The semaphore is initialized with a value of 0: `let dispatchSemaphore = DispatchSemaphore(value: 0)` before. You can see the full final solution in the question.

Comment: @Palle could you have a lookt at this question? It is similiar to this one but a bit different and I am stuck: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62954319/run-for-loop-with-asynchronous-calls-in-order?noredirect=1#comment111329717_62954319