# Making Multiple Requests With Different URLs

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swift, loops

I have a list of id's

**173577
173581
173565
173578
173564
173571
73576
173580**

I want to loop a request with each id in the correct order, but right now it comes back in random order and doesn't get through all the ids.

i also get and error at `let stock = imageArray[indexPath.row]` saying indexpath out of range and i think its because it doesn't get through all the ids

```
        let products = newArray[indexPath.row]

        let id = products.id
        print(id)

        let url = URL(string: "https://www.supremenewyork.com/shop/\(id).json")!
        let request = URLRequest(url: url)
        let session = URLSession.shared
        let task = session.dataTask(with: request) { (data, response, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print("ERROR:", error)

            } else if let data = data {
                do {
                    let response = try JSONDecoder().decode(Images.self, from: data)
                    self.imageArray = response.styles
                    print(self.imageArray)
                    } catch {
                        print(error)
                    }
                } else {
                    print("UNEXPECTED ERROR")
            }
        }
        task.resume()

        let stock = imageArray[indexPath.row]
        let x = stock.biggerZoomedURL
        print(x)
```

The code is working (except `let stock = imageArray[indexPath.row]` error), i just was seeing if there's a way to loop each id in and print them out in order

Comment: `let stock = imageArray[indexPath.row]` should be under the `print(self.imageArray)` inside the completion closure. What are you trying to do here?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Swift 4 async call with for loop execute in order using DispatchGroup, DispatchQueue and DispatchSemaphore](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46863325/swift-4-async-call-with-for-loop-execute-in-order-using-dispatchgroup-dispatchq)

Comment: i cant put it in there @Tj3n i need to be able to use 'stock' variable

Comment: and @JoakimDanielson kinda but how would i do it with my request

Comment: Put most of your code above in a function that takes id and a closure as arguments

Answer (score 0):

`let stock = imageArray[indexPath.row]` seems like you are doing something in `cellForRow:` method. Well, about this index path out of range you can tackle using this code, it makes a safe index.

```
public extension Array {
   public subscript (safe index: Int) -> Element? {
      return self.indices ~= index ? self[index] : nil
   }
}
```

Usage:

```
let stock = imageArray[safe: indexPath.row]
```

OR

If you are hitting URL by simply iterating the array then you can use [DispathGroup](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup).