# For Loop - Alamofire Requests in a synchronous way Swift4 - Execute for loop waiting till async request returns

Tags: ios, synchronization, alamofire, swift4

```
for i in 0 ..< 5 {
                print("Request Number" ,i)
                Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).responseJSON { response in
                    print("Finished request \(i)")
                }
            }
```

In this sample of code, is there any way I can get the above code run in a way such that it prints

```
Request Number 0
Finished request 0
Request Number 1
Finished request 1
Request Number 2
Finished request 2
Request Number 3
Finished request 3
Request Number 4
Finished request 4
```

Comment: @Hardik can you explain how much delay? We can't assume when server response for a request.

Comment: https://github.com/PromiseKit/Alamofire- this may help you I think

Comment: @PPL - Will check it and update. Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait until swift for loop with asynchronous network requests finishes executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906568/wait-until-swift-for-loop-with-asynchronous-network-requests-finishes-executing)

Comment: @AbdelahadDarwish No! This is different issue altogether.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this code

```
for i in 0 ..< 5 {
            print("Request Number" ,i)
            let runLoop = CFRunLoopGetCurrent()
            Alamofire.request("https://httpbin.org/get", parameters: ["foo": "bar"]).responseJSON { response in
                print("Finished request \(i)")
                CFRunLoopStop(runLoop)
            }
            CFRunLoopRun()
        }
```

Comment: Worked ! Thanks!

Comment: @Vamshi Krishna Welcome