# Firebase query not executing in the correct order?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, dispatch-queue

I fetch data and display in a tableView, the problem is the data is not executing in the correct order.

I have tried:

```
            for case let child as DataSnapshot in data!.children.reversed() {
                let newDispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
                let commentID = child.key
                let uid = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "UID").value as! String
                let commentText = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "Comment").value!
                let timeStamp = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeStamp").value!
                let date = ConvertDate(mediaTimestamp: timeStamp as! Double).getDate!
                //print(date, "dsfsdafdasfdsafdsahjkfhfdsafsajkadhffdsfsafsasjkfhsdajkhfdsajkhfjklads")

                newDispatchGroup.enter()

                ref.child("users2").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in
                    print(snapshot, "dshjkfhjkadhfsjkfhsdajkhfdsajkhfjklads")
                    print(date, "dsfsdafdasfdsafdsahjkfhfdsafsajkadhffdsfsafsasjkfhsdajkhfdsajkhfjklads")

                    let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value
                    let profileImage = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImage").value

                    let newUser = User(theuserID: uid, theUsername: username as! String, theprofImage: profileImage as! String)

                    let newComment = Comment(newUser: newUser, text: commentText as! String, timeStamp: date, NcommentID: commentID)
                    self.commentsVC1.arrayOfComments.append(newComment)
                    newDispatchGroup.leave()
                    //completion()
                })
                newDispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
                    print(self.totalComments, "COgfdsdfgfdsgdsfgdfsgfdsgdfsgdskj", self.commentsVC1.arrayOfComments.count)
                    if self.totalComments == self.commentsVC1.arrayOfComments.count {
                        print("COmejkfbdshkafdsagfhksdagfdsakj")
                        self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    }
```

But it did not work either, the order in which the second firebase calls execute is incorrect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved with this:

```
    for case let child as DataSnapshot in snap.children.reversed() {
                    let commentID = child.key
                    let uid = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "UID").value as! String
                    let commentText = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "Comment").value!
                    let timeStamp = child.childSnapshot(forPath: "timeStamp").value!
                    let date = ConvertDate(mediaTimestamp: timeStamp as! Double).getDate!
                    let newUser = User(theuserID: uid)
                    let newComment = Comment(newUser: newUser, text: commentText as! String, timeStamp: date, NcommentID: commentID)
                    self.commentsVC1.arrayOfComments.append(newComment)
                    ref.child("users2").child(uid).observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in

                        let username = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "username").value
                        let profileImage = snapshot.childSnapshot(forPath: "profileImage").value

                        let newUserIner = User(theuserID: uid, theUsername: username as! String, theprofImage: profileImage as! String)
                        newComment.user = newUserIner
                        if self.totalComments == self.commentsVC1.arrayOfComments.count {
                            self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()
                        }
                    })
                }
```

I would use dispatch group here though so one does not have have to check if its done unnecessarily.

Answer (score 0):

You should set up your `notify` closure when you set up your `DispatchGroup`. And you would not need to use a completion closure for you `loadComments` function.

```
let dispatchGroup = DispatchGroup()
dispatchGroup.notify(queue: .main, execute: {
    if self.totalComments == self.commentsVC1.arrayOfComments.count {
        print("COmejkfbdshkafdsagfhksdagfdsakj")
        self.commentsVC1.tableView.reloadData()
    }
})

loadComments()
```

`notify` will be called, when `leave` has been called the same amount of times as `enter`. In your code the last `leave` call is happening before you have set the anything to be notified about.

Comment: I tried this (passing in as argument) and it did not work

Comment: Also the notify only runs 1 time doing this. i dont know why

Comment: The notify will _only_ run once. That is the point of a DispatchGroup - you create it, you use it and then you dispose of it. If you need to do something else, you might need to consider a different approach.

Comment: You can use your updated answer and it might work, if you will use separate DispatchGroups: an outer one and an inner one. The inner ones would call outer's "enter" when are being created, and their "notify" will call "outer's" "leave".