# Swift UITableViewController `await` until all data is loaded before rendering, or re-render after data has been loaded

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, graphql

I am on Swift 4. The goal is to load all the data in an address book, before render the address book in view. In a different language such as `js`, I may use `await` in each item in the loop, before telling the view to render the rows. I am looking for the canonical way to solve this issue in `Swift 4` with `UITableViewController`.

Right now the address book is stored in backend with `Amplify` and `GraphQL`. I have a `User` model of form

```
type User @Model {
  id: ID!
  name: String!
  bio : String!
}
```

and `Contact` of form

```
type Contact @model {
  ownerId: ID!
  userId: ID!
  lastOpened: String
}
```

In `ContactController: UITableViewController.viewDidLoad` I fetch all `Contact` in database where the `ownerId` is my user's id-token, I then create an object using this `contact` information. And then for each `Contact` object instance, I get its corresponding `User` in database when the object is initialized. Per this post: [Wait until swift for loop with asynchronous network requests finishes executing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906568/wait-until-swift-for-loop-with-asynchronous-network-requests-finishes-executing), I am using `Dispatch` group, and then reload the `UITableView` after the loop completes and the `Dispatch` group has ended. But when I `print` to console, I see that the loop completes before the `Contact` object has loaded its `User` information.

Code snippets:

```
class ContactsController: UITableViewController, UISearchResultsUpdating {

        var dataSource : [Contact] = []


        override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            let fetchContactGrp = DispatchGroup()

            fetchContactGrp.enter()

            self.getMyContacts(){ contacts in

                for contact in contacts {

                    let _contactData = Contact(
                          userId     : contact.userId
                        , contactId  : contact.id
                        , timeStamp  : contact.timeStamp
                        , lastOpened : contact.lastOpened
                        , haveAccount: true
                    )

                    _contactData.loadData()
                    self.dataSource.append(_contactData)
                }

            }


            fetchContactGrp.leave()

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }

    }
```

The function `self.getMyContacts` is just a standard `GraphQL` query:

```
func getMyContacts( callBack: @escaping ([Contact]) -> Void ){

    let my_token = AWSMobileClient.default().username
    let contact = Contact.keys
    let predicate = contact.ownerId == my_token! 

    _ = Amplify.API.query(from: Contact.self, where: predicate) { (event) in
        switch event {
            case .completed(let result):
                switch result {
                    case .success(let cts):
                        /// @On success, output a user list
                        callBack(cts)
                    case .failure(let error):
                        break
                }
            case .failed(let error):
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}
```

And the `Contact` object loads the `User` data from database:

```
class Contact {

        let userId: String!
        let contactId: String!

        var name : String
        var bio  : String
        var website: String

        let timeStamp: String
        let lastOpened: String


        init( userId: String, contactId: String, timeStamp: String, lastOpened: String, haveAccount: Bool){

            self.userId     = userId
            self.contactId  = contactId
            self.timeStamp  = timeStamp
            self.lastOpened = lastOpened
            self.haveAccount = haveAccount


            self.name = ""
            self.bio  = ""
            self.website = ""

        }

        func loadData(){

            /// @use: fetch user data from db and populate field on initation
            let _ = Amplify.API.query(from: User.self, byId: self.userId) { (event) in

                switch event {
                    case .completed(let res):
                        switch res{
                            case .success (let musr):
                                if (musr != nil){

                                    let userData = musr!
                                    let em    = genEmptyString()
                                    self.name = (userData.name == em) ? "" : userData.name
                                    self.bio  = (userData.bio == em)  ? "" : userData.bio
                                    self.website = (userData.website == em) ? "" : userData.website

                                    print(">> amplify.query: \(self.name)")

                                } else {
                                    break
                                }
                            default:
                               break
                        }
                    default:
                        print("failed")
                }
            }
        }


    }
```

Comment: The way you are using `DispatchGroup` is wrong. You have to add a completion handler to `loadData()`, then call `enter()` inside the loop in `viewDidLoad ` and leave in the completion handler of `loadData()`. Add `group.notify` and reload the table view in the closure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I posted a more general version of this question here: [Using `DispatchGroup` or some concurency construct to load data and populate cells in `UITableViewController` sequentially](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61431734/using-dispatchgroup-or-some-concurency-construct-to-load-data-and-populate-cel)

And it has been resolved.

Answer (score 0):

It's because the function **getMyContacts()** is performing an Async task and the control goes over that and execute the leave statement. You need to call the leave statement inside the **getMyContacts()** function outside the for loop.

Try the following code:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

            super.viewDidLoad()

            let fetchContactGrp = DispatchGroup()

            fetchContactGrp.enter()

            self.getMyContacts(){ contacts in

                for contact in contacts {

                    let _contactData = Contact(
                          userId     : contact.userId
                        , contactId  : contact.id
                        , timeStamp  : contact.timeStamp
                        , lastOpened : contact.lastOpened
                        , haveAccount: true
                    )

                    _contactData.loadData()
                    self.dataSource.append(_contactData)
                }
                fetchContactGrp.leave()
            }


            fetchContactGrp.wait()

            DispatchQueue.main.async{
                 self.tableView.reloadData()
            }
        }
```

Comment: Don't **wait**, there is no reason to do that. And the `DispatchGroup` syntax is as wrong as in the question.

Comment: @vadian could you provide an alternate solution? I used this example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906568/wait-until-swift-for-loop-with-asynchronous-network-requests-finishes-executing

Comment: Please read my comment to the question. `DispatchGroup` is only useful is `leave()` is called in a completion handler of an asynchronous function. Both the question and the answer ignore the asynchronous behavior of `loadData()`

Comment: @UmerFaroq I get he same behavior as before with `wait`. Just to be clear, when I `print` the exection steps, it enter, wait and leave the dispatch group, *before* initializting `Contact` and loading the user data. @vadian ok I sort of get what you're sayiing now. Could you provide a code smple please?

Comment: Once again, you have to add a completion handler in `loadData` like in `getMyContacts`.

Comment: @vadian still learning the basics, could you provide an example of the completion hander I would need? I get concurency in principle, but its execution in Swift is lost to be, as is how to use the API