# Using `DispatchGroup` or some concurency construct to load data and populate cells in `UITableViewController` sequentially

Tags: ios, swift, dispatchgroup

### Platform:

I am on swift 4 and xcode 11.4

### Use case and desired behavior

The app is loading a feed with potentially 100s or 1000s of items, let's say 500 items. The 500 items will be grabbed once using `Amplify`'s `GraphQL` query, then each item will then load *additional* data. The data will populate the cells in a `UITableViewController`. Ideally this process would happen in the following exact sequence:

1. `query` 500 items
2. cell_1 load additional data.
3. cell_1 render data and display in `UITableViewController`
4. cell_2 load additional data.
5. cell_2 render data and display in `UITableViewController`

...

1001. cell_500 load additional data
1002. cell_500 render data and display in `UITableViewController`

So the user will see a "waterfall" of cells being rendered in the feed.

### Question

This seems like a use case that require some finer control of execution, which would need this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/dispatch/dispatchgroup

I am new to Swift so this is a bit advanced for me. Provided is the stub for `GraphQL` query, and class function that loads additional data, and the top level `UITableViewController`. Please instruct how I would use `DispatchGroup`.

```
class Feed: UITableViewController {
    
    var dataSource: [FullItem] = []

    override func viewDidLoad(){
       super.viewDidLoad()
       
       queryItem{ items
           
           for item in items {
              let itemInstanceWithMoreData = FullItem( id: item.id )
              itemInstanceWithMoreData.loadFullData()
           }
         
       }           
    }
}


func queryItems( callBack: @escaping ([Item]) -> Void ){

    _ = Amplify.API.query(from: Item.self, where: predicate) { (event) in
        switch event {
            case .completed(let result):
                switch result {
                    case .success(let xs):
                        callBack(xs)
                    case .failure: 
                        break
                }
            case .failed: 
                break
            default:
                break
        }
    }
}


class FullItem {
    
    id: String
    name: String?
    
    init( id ){ self.id = id; self.name = "" }

    
    func loadData(){

        let _ = Amplify.API.query(from: FullItem.self, byId: self.id) { (event) in
            
            switch event {
                case .completed(let res):
                    switch res{
                        case .success (let musr):
                            if (musr != nil){
                                self.name = musr!.name
                            } else {
                                break
                            }
                        default:
                           break
                    }
                default:
                    print("failed")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### addendum

If the sequence I am asking is not possible, I would also settle for `query` 500 items, `load` additional data for each one, then rendering the cells. But either way, the cell should not render with empty data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your example is incomplete and doesn't compile so this is the short version

Declare `loadData()`

```
func loadData(completion: @escaping () -> Void) {
```

and make sure that `completion()` is called in **any** case (this is crucial!) for example

```
default:
    completion()
    print("failed")
```

To use `DispatchGroup` properly you have to call `enter` **inside** the loop before calling the asynchronous task and call `leave` in the completion handler of the task. At the end **outside** the loop implement `notify`

```
override func viewDidLoad(){
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let group = DispatchGroup()

    queryItems { items

        for item in items {
            group.enter()
            let itemInstanceWithMoreData = FullItem( id: item.id )
            itemInstanceWithMoreData.loadData {
                group.leave()
            }
        }

        group.notify(queue: .main) {
            self.tableView.reloadData()
        }

    }
}
```

To insert and update the items serially **in order** you need an asynchronous `Operation` and a serial `OperationQueue`. `DispatchGroup` doesn't preserve the order.

Comment: It sounds like he wants to load the additional data in a serially. You're loading the additional data concurrently here.

Comment: @Rob thank you! I forgot on line in the example, which is where I would push `itemInstanceWithMoreData` into the`dataSource`.  right now I do it below the line             itemInstanceWithMoreData.loadData {
                group.leave()
            }.