# How can i sort Alphabetically my Table View, of custom object?

Tags: arrays, swift, uikit

So my idea, is to once is retrieved from the API, that they are shown alphabatecally by the value 'name' of the Charact object which are all them stored in to pokemons array.

I would like to know how i would be able to sort my list of Pokemons so they appear in alphabetical order

Here is my Object code:

```
class Charact: Codable  {
    
    var id: Int?
    var isDefault: Bool?
    var isMega : Bool?
    var isBattleOnly : Bool?
    var name: String?
    var sprites: Sprite?
    
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case isDefault = "is_default"
        case isMega = "is_mega"
        case isBattleOnly = "is_battle_only"
        case id
        case name
        case sprites
    }
    
}
```

Here is the code : [Code in paste-bin](https://pastebin.com/0dgqfkah)

Comment: This is not SwiftUI -- this is UIKit

Comment: You need just to sort `pokemons`, like `pokemons = pokemons.sorted { $0.name < $1.name }` BUT, you have an issue, is that `images` index needs to be synched. You shouldn't use different array, but one.

Comment: Please show us the code of `Charact`. However, first just try to use Swift's standard `sort` methods on your array where you assign its value. What's the problem there?

Comment: It'd be better idea to define a new class or struct which contains both the pokemon and it's image (let's call it PokemonWithImage, then once you have the array of [PokemonWithImage] you can sort it in a similar way as @Larme mentioned. In this way you won't need to worry about the sequence of the images. And then you call tableView.reloadData()

Comment: Something that's not related to the question, is your downloadPokemonsInfo() function. API calls are asynchronous so there are better and more reliable ways to do that. see this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35906568/wait-until-swift-for-loop-with-asynchronous-network-requests-finishes-executing

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that you want to stick to your code, try this out:

```
func downloadPokemonsInfo(){
        for i  in 1...MAX_POKEMONS{
            connection.getCharact(withId: i) { charact in
                if let charact = charact, let id = charact.id{
                    self.pokemons[id-1] = charact
                    if let imageURL = charact.sprites?.frontDefault{
                        self.connection.getSprite(withURLString: imageURL) { image in
                            self.imagesDownload = self.imagesDownload + 1
                            if let image = image {
                                self.images[id - 1] = image
                            }
                            if self.imagesDownload == self.MAX_POKEMONS{
                                let zipped = zip(self.pokemons, self.images)
                                let zippedSorted = zipped.sorted { one, two in
                                    guard let c1 = one.0, let c2 = two.0, let n1 = c1.name, let n2 = c2.name else { return false }
                                    return n1 < n2
                                }
                                self.pokemons = zippedSorted.map { $0.0 }
                                self.images = zippedSorted.map { $0.1 }
                                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                                    self.tableView.reloadData()
                                    self.tableView.alpha = 1
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
 
    }
```

Comment: I tried this one but is the same error i got when i tried to do sorted by method.https://ibb.co/qp8pfJP. This didn't worked neither https://ibb.co/cJppb2w

Comment: same thing bruh https://ibb.co/FbXbNrh, im so desperate bruh

Comment: Character is optional, is name also optional?

Comment: Your question, solved my problem. I just erased the optinal value to my name atributte of the Charact class :). Thank you!!!

Comment: can you show the whole error message?

Comment: I just tested this and it's working for me:
let zippedSorted = zipped.sorted { $0.0!.name! < $1.0!.name! }
But updated the answer to avoid forced unwrapping.

Comment: If the edited version answers your question, please mark it as accepted.